# Detecting mouse moves and key strokes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want that when user is idle for some particular time and mouse doesnot moves  on system than it starts counting time from then ownwards and when user moves mouse then time stops and i can save this time in a varianble

Comment: Only application wide or system wide?

Comment: i want when user starts any activity on anywhere on his system then time stops..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GetLastInputInfo API call.
The following code is mainly from here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetLastInputInfo.html

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Structure LASTINPUTINFO
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public cbSize As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public dwTime As Integer
End Structure
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
End Function

Dim idletime As Integer
Dim lastInputInf As New LASTINPUTINFO()
Public Function GetLastInputTime() As Integer
    idletime = 0
    lastInputInf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInf)
    lastInputInf.dwTime = 0

    If GetLastInputInfo(lastInputInf) Then
        idletime = Environment.TickCount - lastInputInf.dwTime
    End If

    If idletime > 0 Then
        Return idletime / 1000
    Else : Return 0
    End If
End Function

Private sumofidletime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0)
Private LastLastIdletime As Integer = 0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim it As Integer = GetLastInputTime()
    If LastLastIdletime > it Then
        Label1.Text = "IDLE STATE CHANGED!"
        sumofidletime = sumofidletime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LastLastIdletime))
        Label2.Text = "Sum of idle time: " & sumofidletime.ToString
      Else
        Label1.Text = GetLastInputTime()
    End If
    LastLastIdletime = it
End Sub
End Class
```

This code displays the seconds the user has been idle since the last input action in the label on every timer tick. It also checks if the idle state has changed. So at this point you can react to it and save the `LastLastIdletime` as the amount of time in seconds that the user was inactive.

Comment: but also i want that idle time starts when user is idle for 5 minutes but is starts at that time only

Comment: So? Just check if the time is > 5 minutes with a simple `if` then. SO is not a code-generation tool and you should do at least some of the work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent having to handle this for many controls you can rearrange things a bit and cache the information needed to know if cursor has moved and how long the idle time is, to do this you need a Point variable and a Date variable. The Timer needs to tick all the time. In addition, to balance the cursor Show/Hide calls you need a variable to keep track of its visibility state. Here is the complete code sample:

`Private loc As Point, idle As Date, hidden As Boolean`

`Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If loc <> Cursor.Position Then
        If hidden Then
            Cursor.Show()
            hidden = False
        End If
        loc = Cursor.Position
        idle = Date.Now
    ElseIf Not hidden AndAlso (Date.Now - idle).TotalSeconds > 3 Then

        Cursor.Hide()
        hidden = True
    End If
End Sub`

This Timer can tick each 1/2-1 seconds depending on how responsive you want it, the idle time is set to 3 seconds. The code should be easy to understand when you read it and give it some thought, if not ask