# Close App after 1 minute of inactive time

Tags: vb.net, timer

I want the vb.net app to close after 1 minute of inactive time.
this code will close the app after 1 min for active user as well.

```
Dim app As Application

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    aTimer.Interval = 60000

    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    aTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    app.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: First question is what constitutes activity?  Is a simple wiggle of the mouse enough or does it have to be some form of input (typing or clicks)? And active in ONLY your application or any program?  Really you just need a flag that gets reset in the activity event(s) depending on the answer above, then in the OnTimedEvent, check that flag and take appropriate action.

Comment: @Hursey it need to be click or type on my application, if the user is not using my application, it should close after 1 min

Comment: So, as per original comment then.  Create a form level variable in you app.  Maybe just a boolean or if you want to get a little more advanced a time stamp.  Set that in the appropriate event handlers (Either control or Form level), then in OnTimedEvent, if your variable shows there has been recent activity, then don't exit.  Might also want to consider the scope of aTimer.  Think you want that as form level var.  And not 100% sure what _Dim app As Application_ intent is as you never give it a value, yet call methods in OnTimedEvent

Comment: You don't really need a field to track activity. You can restart the `Timer` each time there's activity and then just close the form if and when the `Tick` event is raised. If the `Interval` is one minute and the `Tick` event is raised then you know there's been no activity for one minute. You'd need to handle all the appropriate `MouseClick`, `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events but you'd have to do that anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878847/14171304

Comment: @RanjanSapkota Did you check my answer? Please, if it answers your question, mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follow.

Create a `System.Timers.Timer`in your window.xaml.vb file:

```
Private WithEvents CloseTimer As New Timers.Timer
```

In the constructor, add the following lines:

```
 CloseTimer.Interval = 1000 * 5 ' Remember that interval is set in milliseconds
 CloseTimer.Start()
```

Every time the mouse is moved on the window, the timer has to be reset, so use the `MouseMove` event like this:

```
Private Sub Window_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    ResetTimer()
End Sub
```

And define the `ResetTimer()` subroutine as follow:

```
Private Sub ResetTimer()
    CloseTimer.Stop()
    CloseTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

Obviously you can change / improve that condition: for example, if the user doesn't move the mouse because he's typing in a Textbox, you should manage this condition, too:

```
Private Sub Window_PreviewKeyDown() Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
    ResetTimer()
End Sub
```

This will catch all `KeyDown` event from the window and all its children controls.

Finally add the `Timer_Elapsed` event, which will be fired when the timer interval elapsed:

```
Private Shared Sub Timer_Elapsed() Handles CloseTimer.Elapsed
    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub
```

If you notice there are more conditions to keep the application running, just find the appropriate event and in its subscription call ResetTimer().

Note that this method is quite simple but, depending on the architecture of the application, there may be better methods.